# apache url rewrite not working as expected

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

looks as if it's working now, i'm not doing anything... stange...

I want to write 
http://www.1024jobs.net/jobs/view/17.jhtml
to 
http://www.1024jobs.com/jobs/view/17.jhtml

so i have tried either of below rules in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^jobs/view/([0-9]+)\.jhtml$   http://www.1024jobs.com/jobs/view/$1.jhtml [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^jobs/view/([^.]+).jhtml$   http://www.1024jobs.com/jobs/view/$1.jhtml [L,R=301]
```

but it's always translating to below url
http://www.1024jobs.net/jobs/view/17.jhtml
to 
http://www.1024jobs.com/jobs/view/.jhtml

however, just found below is translated correctly....
http://www.1024jobs.net/jobs/view/16.jhtml
can anyone help and explain? thx